# SQL code to identify local part of email address

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, substring

I am trying to write SQL code to identify the local part of an email address in its multiple variations and only return the characters (removing any extraneous periods or +someextension).

Example:

```
firstlast@gmail.com
firstlast+2020@gmail.com
fir.st.la.st@gmail.com
```

Should all return:

```
firstlast@gmail.com
```

I'm unsure how to do this. I know that I could use substring to get the part before the @ sign but am unsure how to eliminate the other extra unnecessary punctuation or extensions.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. String and regex functions are quite vendor-specific.

Comment: Using MySQL, just added tag

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Any version is fine. It's actually a brain teaser I've been asked so minor variations of the answer are allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0+, you can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split the string into parts before and after the `@`, and then use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) on the first part to remove the `.`s or characters after (and including) a `+`. For example:

```
create table data (email varchar(30));
insert into data values
('firstlast@gmail.com'),
('firstlast+2020@gmail.com'),
('fir.st.la.st@gmail.com');
select concat(regexp_replace(substring_index(email, '@', 1), '\\.|\\+.*$', ''), 
              '@',
              substring_index(email, '@', -1))
from data
```

Output:

```
firstlast@gmail.com
firstlast@gmail.com
firstlast@gmail.com
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.com](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60946245ee719dc0b9eb416a8f287479)

Comment: Thank you, this works and seems the most generalizable to the problem.

Comment: @user3242036 it will definitely allow you to remove any different characters from the first part by placing them in a character class e.g. to remove `.`, `_` and `-` you would just change the regex to `[._-]|\\+.*$`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the rules you want to implement are:

- Remove the periods before the `@`.
- If there is a `+` before the `@`, only take the character before that.
- All valid email characters are allowed, and that includes (at least) letters, digits, and underscore.

The following implements these rules:

```
select concat(replace(substring_index(substring_index(email, '@', 1), '+', 1), '.', ''), substring_index(email, '@', -1))
```

Comment: @user3242036 . . . I believe this works *correctly*.  But I see that Nick edited his answer *after* I wrote this, so that now looks more correct.  I answered because Nick's answer did not work generally.